# iOS: Documents directory being 'cleaned'

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, core-data

### **The Situation**

I have an app that stores a core data database in the documents directory. It seems to work well for the most part, except for the fact a few users (of a very large number) are complaining their data just 'disappeared'.

It's a carefully/well coded app, no weird errors or crashes coming from Core Data.

### My Suspicion

iOS sometimes shows the word 'cleaning' beneath app icons when storage space is low. This cleans some directories to free up space.

### Help!

Could this be the cause? If so, how can I stop this? Any light that can be shed on this would be much appreciated.

Comment: iOS does cleanup but that's only Temp or Cache dirs and not docs dir. It never touches that. Most likely the users whose data is disappearing must be doing some weird stuff. Perhaps they are deleting & reinstalling the app. Maybe they are entering weird non-ascii stuff etc. Possibilities are endless unless they tell you exactly the steps to reproduce this error it would be impossible to debug.

Comment: I concur with Sam. Documents is supposed to be used for data the user owns, and should never be cleared by the system. Cache and temp directories ARE purged to clear space. Post the code that creates your core data database. Also fetch the path to the backing store and log it. Also log the path to your documents directory and make absolutely sure you're saving into the sandboxed documents directory.

Comment: If appropriate for your app, you should also look into implementing Core Data in iCloud: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/iCloudDesignGuide/Chapters/DesignForCoreDataIniCloud.html

Comment: @DuncanC yeah, thanks. I'm going to send Core Data NSError logs to an analytics server to get some more info, maybe that will shed some more light.

Comment: @JordanSmith I'm also experiencing this, it happens for a very small number of users, and it actually happened to me whilst I had the phone connected to the debugger. I managed to extract the app container before and after and indeed all of the contents of the Documents directory were purged. Perhaps it's coincidental, but to me it happened after an app crash. Sadly I forgot to capture a sysdiagnose. I strongly believe this is an iOS bug, seen it happening on iOS 14 and iOS 15.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The documents directory is the recommended place to store a core data database and iOS will never "clean up" anything stored there.

Users can manually delete files in the Documents directory, by uninstalling the app or (if you've enabled it in info.plist) browsing their phone from in iTunes.

Most users do not expect their data to be destroyed when they uninstall an app (Macs and PCs would leave the data in place for example), so this is probably what's happening.

You should consider storing a second copy of the data on your server, or on the user's iCloud account. That way it won't be destroyed by an uninstall. If it's your server, then you can justify charging money for this feature (recurring revenue is good right?).

Backups to iTunes and iCloud will both include your database, so you can instruct users to restore to a recent backup to get their data back.

Also double check your code to see how it handles an out of disk space error when attempting to save changes to the database. Depending how you're using Core Data, this could go bad.

These days Core Data in iCloud or some other cloud solution is the best approach.

Comment: Thanks, I do implement iCloud, but the first sync takes 20 seconds or so - quite possibly they do not wait this long. Thanks for that.